# cannot find RedHat arm in az cli or azurerm

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-powershell, azure-cli

After running:

```
az vm image terms --urn RedHat:RHEL:7.8:7.8.2020090816 show
```

Error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: 'RedHat:RHEL:7.8:7.8.2020090816' is misspelled or not recognized by the system.
```

In addition, `centos-7-8` returns the info:

```
Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Publisher 'procomputers' -Product 'centos-7-8' -Name 'centos-7-8'

Publisher         : procomputers
Product           : centos-7-8
Plan              : centos-7-8
LicenseTextLink   : https://storelegalterms.blob.core.windows.net/legalterms/3E5ED_legalterms_PROCOMPUTERS%253a24CENTOS
                    %253a2D7%253a2D8%253a24CENTOS%253a2D7%253a2D8%253a24T622IBUBKL6J3MHL5NUAWG2XNZ5H5FVSJGLCOC54LB63AGI
                    ONYH5CDZVDEYDONEFK2NHKCZROAP7ZU5PLZHXJ5ZNBFEUCBOWWMC4DSY.txt
PrivacyPolicyLink : http://www.procomputers.com/privacy-policy.html
Signature         : TE7WPYLUZF56EK3MSEL4MNYDVDO6XAXI4BAUXAQHN3SLVFU4MYTVAMGWTTXXM6VLYZ7R4O7EZP53YCRDYRZPUZ3LNINTFLZ74XG
                    XKYA
Accepted          : True
Signdate          : 23/10/2020 11:20:29 AM
```

However, to run same command for RedHat 7.8 arm on marketplace, returns an error.

```
Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Publisher 'RedHat' -Product 'RedHatEnterpriseLinux78-ARM' -Name 'RedHatEnterpriseLinux78-ARM'
Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms : The Publisher: 'RedHat' does not make available Offer: 'RedHatEnterpriseLinux78-ARM',
Plan: 'RedHatEnterpriseLinux78-ARM' in your Subscription/Azure account’s region: ''. Correlation Id:
'ad2a0b91-d89a-4a8f-9cd5-bb85ff95d897'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Publisher 'RedHat' -Product 'RedHatEnter ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.MarketplaceOrdering.Cmdlets.Agreements.GetAzureRmMarketplaceTer
   ms
```

As I am trying to deploy VM and using RedHat 7.8 ARM via Terraform, I need to set terms as accepted, and deploy VM through Terraform.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct format of the Azure CLI command to run is:

```
az vm image terms show --urn <urn>
```

Running this for the given image returns:

```
 az vm image terms show --urn RedHat:RHEL:7.8:7.8.2020090816
 Image 'RedHat:RHEL:7.8:7.8.2020090816' has no terms to accept.
```

To check the same via Azure PowerShell, for let's say the West US 2 region, you can run:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzVMImage -Location "westus2" -PublisherName "RedHat" -Offer "RHEL" -Skus "7.8" -Version "7.8.2020090816"
```

Output:

```
Id               : /Subscriptions/<Subscription ID>/Providers/Microsoft.Compute/Locations/westus2/Publishers/RedHat/ArtifactTypes/VMImag
                   e/Offers/RHEL/Skus/7.8/Versions/7.8.2020090816
Location         : westus2
PublisherName    : RedHat
Offer            : RHEL
Skus             : 7.8
Version          : 7.8.2020090816
FilterExpression :
Name             : 7.8.2020090816
HyperVGeneration : V1
OSDiskImage      : {
                     "operatingSystem": "Linux"
                   }
PurchasePlan     : null
DataDiskImages   : []
```

Since the `PurchasePlan` for this image is `null`, it means this image doesn't have additional terms to accept before programmatic deployment.